# Use Different CSS for Different Routes In React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, routes

I need to be able to use CSS in different routes in React. I would much prefer to not use SASS, but if it is the only solution I will use it.

My `Homepage (index.js)` needs to use `index.css` and my `Other Page (page2.js)` needs to use `page2.css` (example names)

File Structure:

```
-src
  -components
  -pages
     -css
        -index.css
        -page2.css
     -index.js
     -page2.js
```

Files:

```
// src/pages/index.js
import React from 'react'
import './css/index.css'

const Homepage = () => {
  return (
    <!-- unrelated HTML -->
  )
}

export default Homepage

// src/pages/page2.js
import React from 'react'
import './css/page2.css'

const Page2 = () => {
  return (
    <!-- unrelated HTML -->
  )
}

export default Page2
```

It really seems like this should work fine, but it loads both CSS files at once and they overlap and glitch out.

I would really like to avoid using things like SASS as stated above. Is there any way to do this with routes without doing something hacky like changing a `link` tag whenever the page changes?

Comment: CRA and vite should do this out of the box for you IIRC.

Comment: @super I don't think it does anymore, I have tried some re-ordering and it still keeps both stylesheets in one route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you use css modules, css modules are just normal css files but applied to a css standarized structure to manage multiple css files among pages.

For this you should:

1. Rename your css files to "homePage.module.css / page2.module.css"
2. Move each css file to its page directory

It would look like this

```
-src
  -components
  -pages
        -page2.js
        -page2.module.css
     -index.js
     -homePage.module.css
```

Finally import each css file in its corresponding page
Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works well its just is tedious to convert all my classes to the module css classes.

Comment: This is a nextjs-only solution afaik. Do we have anything for react on its own?

Comment: Nevermind, works with React too (with Vite at least).